# Is there a way to replace an image's pixel with a file/bufferedreader?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, pixel

I'm trying to build one of those composite image programs where you feed it X images and it'll make another photo out of those images. Now, I've got everything from the comparison equation to getting files out of the source folder for comparison, but I can't seem to figure out how to replace a singular pixel with the images I already have. If this can be done with a bufferedImage/file, how? If not is there another way I could accomplish it?

Comment: Reading the files would be an issue, as many file formats are compressed and don't always store there image data in a linear fashion. You could load the images using `ImageIO`, which will give you a `BufferedImage` or there might be other libraries available which don't have to load the entire image in order for you to manipulate it

Comment: I suggest using `ImageIO` and `BufferedImage`s too, but read up on [Working with Images](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) and [Compositing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html)  in the Java2D tutorial before you start. PS: Some (uncompressed) formats may support [replacing pixels through the `ImageWriter` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html#canReplacePixels(int)), but I don't think you'll need this just yet..

Answer (score -1):

```
//create simple image
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(320, 240, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
//set pixel color RED at x=10, y=10
img.setRGB(10, 10, Color.red.getRGB());

//get pixel color as RGB
int rgb = img.getRGB(50, 50);

//get components of RGB as separated R, G and B values
int red = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
int green = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
int blue = rgb & 0xFF;
```

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I have an empty Bufferedimage object and I'd like to fill it with other BufferedImages. Is there a way to set the pixel in a BufferedImage to another BufferedImage object or something similar?